# HTML img tags won't work though the link is correct

Tags: html, image, src

HTML img tags won't work though the link is correct

I have been trying for a long time to solve this problem and I searched a lot of websites and tested everything but to no avail.

I just want to show the picture.

```
<img src='https://jdwel.com/image/teams/eng_newcastle_united.png' width="50px" height="50px" alt="This is an image"/>
```

Click here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3r0du.png) to show the result of this code

Comment: Can you further elaborate the problem.What do you mean not working?.Is your network call is blocked?

Comment: This doesnt seem to be a Code Issue rather than something blocking it from loading. The `<img>` Tag in and of itself works fine for me. So you might check on your end if the Network couldn't load it or your Antivirus blocked it... . Otherwise we need some more context how this image is implemented/ is used.

Comment: I extract some data from this website using web scraping and at first it was fine but shortly after this problem appeared that the pictures do not show. and console log says: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()

Comment: Click here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3r0du.png) to show the result of this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems to be fine. Could you add the console logs for this error.

Since you are getting a **403 error**, it seems your request is getting blocked which comes when you access resource you do not have access to

Comment: thank you, i will try extracting the data from another website

Answer (score 0):

Attributes height="50", width="50" need pixel values, without % sign. Additionally, use css to style the dimensions. [Details here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_width.asp), explaining img tag. If still not working, image have have hot linking protected.

Comment: Please open console log (developer tools), and see an error message. It does not seem like a coding issue.

Comment: it says: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()